# PowerShell from Batch File on Network Folder using Admin Accounts: Cannot Find Drive Specified

Tags: powershell, batch-file, admin, network-drive

I have a batch file that will run a PS script from my floating desktop after prompting for Admin credentials, however when I place the batch and PS file on the network to run, it says

```
N:\folder\folder2\folder3\Powershell.bat
The System cannot find the drive specified, and lists my mapped N:\ drive and directory.
```

Strangely, when I log into Windows on the same Admin AD account. Not requiring me to prompt the password because I am already Admin, it fixes this issue. Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
write-output "Enter your ADMIN credentials to continue..."
EXIT
```

I'm fairly new to scripting, so please help me out, I tried to list the exact directory but it didn't work. I believe it MUST be with some issues with using my Admin account. This domain must require my Admin account before I can run the scripts. It was working last week so I'm pretty lost...

Comment: Mapped drives are not system-wide, when you start PowerShell as another user account, it cannot see your mapped drives. When you run a process as another user account, it does not run Windows login scripts. When you login as an admin and have mapped drives and run PowerShell as you, it can see your mapped drives.

Comment: I see, that's very smart, can the batch file first map the drive as admin then continue? Alternatively, how would I change the batch file to run from a directory on the network? I may have had the syntax wrong I tried a combination of cd \\ and it did not work.

Comment: What's the point of the batch file?

Comment: It is to run the PS script that is inside the same folder.

Comment: So, you're starting a powershell.exe from a .bat-file in order to run Start-Process to start another powershell.exe to run your .ps1-file?

Comment: I see what you're saying, this script was semi copied from this blog: http://www.howtogeek.com/204088/how-to-use-a-batch-file-to-make-powershell-scripts-easier-to-run/ on step 4. But it actually works quite well when it is not on the network, so I don't feel like there is anything inherently wrong.